# Timeout while connecting to remote debugger in Ubuntu

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger

I'm running react-native in the following environments:-

```
Environment:
  OS: Linux 4.4
  Node: 6.11.1
  Yarn: 0.22
  npm: 5.5.1
  Watchman: 4.5.0
  Xcode: N/A
  Android Studio: Not Found

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.0.0 => 16.0.0
  react-native: 0.51.0 => 0.51.0
```

I'm getting "Timeout while connecting to remote debugger in real android device" issue in chrome whenever I'm try to debug js remotely. I have also test the app in mac OS x it working fine with remote js debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi this issue is similar to like this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16674

I have resolved this issue by degrading the react-native version. RN 0.49.3.